# Given a image, a pixel point and a radious in pixels. How do I find the pixel coordenate of the circle border it creates

Tags: python, algorithm, image, geometry

Given an image matrix, I want to find the pixel points coordinates of all points/pixels in the border of a given circle with center (x,y), where x and y are integers and radius r, where r is also an integer. Considering the border is 1 pixel thick. Ony this outer edge is what I need to find. I'm having trouble because I only have integers to work with. I tried Manhattan distance but it gives me a square rotated in 45 degrees. I don't really know how to move forward

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I saw your last question, and seems you need expanding circle.

Note that simple drawing  of circumference pixels  might produce small empty spaces. Example for drawing circles of radius 1,2,...,n:

[image]

But you can complete integer circle drawing algorithms like Bresenham's one.

Increase r value one-by-one. Generate sequence of pixel coordinates with Bresenham's algorithm in the first octant. Draw pixel if it is not filled yet (from another cell center), and check if lower pixel is filled  - if not, draw it to remove empty space. Do the same for 7 symmetric pixels and their neighbors (bottom for the second octant and so on)

Comment: I see, for the top half, I just need to check for the pixel immediately below to make sure all pixels are painted? That way I wouldn't need to run over the entire circle inner wards, right?

Comment: If the purpose is to draw a thick circle (a filled ring), this is an XY problem. Drawing several circles of increasing radius is not the preferred way.

Comment: Most known implementations of Bresenham algorithm generate one octant of circle, other parts might be produced by reflections. You generate point and below point and check both in main octant and in all reflected coordinates too.

Comment: @Yves Daoust [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70177489/) is about increasing regions

Comment: I edited it, but I wanted the regions to increase in a circular matter. So this solves what I wanted. English is not my first language so I might have expressed myself wrongly in the previous question

Comment: Ouch, this is even worse that I thought ! Definitely an XY problem as the target is a Voronoi diagram.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the center is the origin (if not, you can easily translate), what you are after is the outline of the region defined by

```
x² + y² - r² ≤ 0.
```

For a given x, this is the largest y that verifies the constraint. In other words,

```
x² + y² - r² ≤ 0 < x² + (y+1)² - r² = x² + y² - r² + 2y + 1.
```

Now if you increment x,

```
(x+1)² + y² - r² = x² + y² - r² + 2x + 1 ≤ 0 < (x+1)² + (y+1)² = x² + y² - r² + 2x + 2y + 2
```

may become false and you need to adjust y by decrementing it.

This is the essence of the incremental algorithm for circles. You keep x² + y² - r² updated and make x, y adjustments unit by unit. This only involves integer arithmetic. In fact, only additions, subtractions and comparisons ! As the coordinates vary by at most one each time, the curve will be continuous.

I did not mention a little complication, that implies eight different cases: x and y may need to be incremented or decremented, and x can vary quicker that y, or conversely. These correspond to a decomposition of the plane in the eight main octants.